# d3 trying to use callbacks "i" as index

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

For a uni class I have to write a visualisation. Therefor I want to write a single horizontal bar which shows the amout of a dataset on percental base. I figured out the theory on how to do this but now im stucking one specific problem:

I have a dataset as a csv `id,name,age` and everything is working fine exept one thing. in order to get the new x position of a "bar" I have to calcualte the value from the width and the x value of the pre drawed bar. So far so good.

to calculate the widht I have the following function:

```
function calcWidth(data,i,scale) {
  return scale(parseInt(dataset[i].age));
}
```

which gives me the width of a, by i specified rect.
The function to calculate the x value looks like the following:

```
function calcX(data,i,scale) {
  if(i == 0) { // because i=0-1 would not be possible and zero anyhow
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    var xold = svg.select("rect[id='"+i-1+"']").attr("x");
    console.log(xold);
    return parseFloat(xold) + calcWidth(data,i-1,scale);
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I try to do this I get a mistake, in oder to get an insight whether the  whole **xold** line is working or not I want to `console.log(xold);` and see there all I get printed is `null` for every `i`.

I tried the xold line within a normal for loop and there it is working I get a value for every i.

Maybe one of you has an idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding some brackets around the i-1:

```
var xold = svg.select("rect[id='"+(i-1)+"']").attr("x");
```

Otherwise javascript will first concatenate the i onto the string (using the "string `+`) and then the `-1` won't behave as you expect.

It also seems like you are giving your `rect`s ids which are just numbers. I know that there is sometimes problems in HTML with ids which start with a number, I'm not sure if this is also the case in SVG but I would suggest giving them ids like `r1`, `r2` etc

If this doesn't help then can you put a copy of your code up on jsfiddle.net for us to play around with?